# Lightning Components - <force:inputfield> Not working for certain field types?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, inputfield, bug, forceinputfield

Is force:inputfield not working for certain field types? I've put together a simple Lightning component I'm finding the following:

- Picklists - Are rendered as disabled (this is an issue I'm aware of from other questions, but including here for completeness)
- Text Area fields, I get the following error:

  This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
  Error during init [Mismatch at 7:0 client expected markup://force:inputField but got original markup://force:inputfield providing markup://ui:inputTextArea from server  for creationPath = 0/*[0]/$/*[0]/$/*[0]/*[0]/*[0]]
- Date Fields, I get the following error:

  This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
  Error during init [Mismatch at 7:0 client expected markup://force:inputField but got original markup://force:inputfield providing markup://ui:inputDate from server  for creationPath = 0/*[0]/$/*[0]/$/*[0]/*[0]/*[0]]

I've already found that there are instances where  isn't rendered at all and found this workaround to get the picklists working:

[Lightning Component initialization after redirect](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/119455/lightning-component-initialization-after-redirect//)

But that doesn't appear to be the issue here. Is anybody else seeing this error?

Here is the simple component on which I'm getting the error:

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="record" access="private" type="Custom_Object__c" default="{'sobjectType' : 'Custom_Object__c','Long_Text__c' : 'Long Text Exmaple','Date_Field__c' : '1900-04-01'}"/>
        <force:inputfield value="{!v.outcome.Example_Field__c}"/>
```

The component is closed off after this.

I can use ui:inputtextarea, etc, but there are certain fields which have no easy way to build without force:inputfield