# Not able to Use Force:inputField in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Hi I am trying to get look and feel of standard field in the lightning component, but I can't find any ways of doing that.
When I am trying to use force:inputField, it is not even displaying any field.

Here is what I am trying

```
 <aura:attribute name="customObject" type="CustomObject__c" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'CustomObject__c'}"/>
 <force:inputField aura:id="contactName" value="{!v.customObject.Status__c}"/>
```

Comment: Status__c is a picklist field

Comment: what do you want lightning styling for outfieldField?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I've updated the code, its input field that I am trying to use.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000MLS4IAO - might help.

Comment: is this field a dependent pickList?

Comment: This field is just an example, that I need the same look and field of a field, it can be Picklist, Lookup, Date, Checkbox, Text or Phone number field it can be any type of field, and it is suppose to inherit the look and feel of field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make force:inputField working, first need to disable lightning debug

And for more detail this link will help
[Lightning Component initialization after redirect](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/119455/lightning-component-initialization-after-redirect/131610#131610)